Android Game app keep crashed on internal browser set up(
The game is set with internal browser using capacitor support.
The stack trace is as below,
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3644)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3781)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:138)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2306)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7918)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:2200)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1839)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:5507)
  at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult (ComponentActivity.java:753)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:5465)
  at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult (ComponentActivity.java:734)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:5963)
  at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api16Impl.startActivity (ContextCompat.java:978)
  at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity (ContextCompat.java:318)
  at androidx.browser.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl (CustomTabsIntent.java:483)
  at com.capacitorjs.plugins.browser.Browser.open (Browser.java:112)
  at com.capacitorjs.plugins.browser.BrowserControllerActivity.open (BrowserControllerActivity.java:43)
  at com.capacitorjs.plugins.browser.BrowserPlugin.lambda$open$0 (BrowserPlugin.java:72)
  at com.capacitorjs.plugins.browser.BrowserPlugin.$r8$lambda$I9bLDRWh7vl57kOTAfjVKp5lWOU
  at com.capacitorjs.plugins.browser.BrowserPlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onControllerReady
  at com.capacitorjs.plugins.browser.BrowserControllerActivity.onCreate (BrowserControllerActivity.java:19)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8342)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8321)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1417)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3625)

we have checked all of the links sending to browser to open and all are in correct format.
the integration using https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/main/browser/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/browser/Browser.java.
Using androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0
